# Rest Versioning with Mime Types - Default Version for */*

Tags: rest, jax-rs, versioning, mime-types

I have implemented versioning on my REST services with CXF by defining a vendor mime type which works fine when the correct accept header is passed.

However, when a client does not pass an accept header but asterix/asterix my service defaults to returning the first version of the service.

Okay, this is correct as the client has specified that they accept anything but I would like it to default to the second latest version of the service.

Is there a way to specify that this service is the default one that should be used in this case?

Thanks

Service One Annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(value = {CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_CUSTOM_MEDIATYPE_JSON_V1})
```

Service Two Annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_CUSTOM_MEDIATYPE_JSON_V2})
```

Comment: It seems that other implementations of JAXRS support quality weighting for this situation where the higher weighted service gets chosen, however, I can't find anything related to CXF and this . .

Answer (score 1):

The solution below only would works for maintaining 2 versions at the same time:

**Remove the @Produces of the older version (v1).**

This will force the use of WildCard on the v1 which (therefore) will be **less specific** than your @Produce in v2.

- Without MediaType, the dispatcher will pick up the most specific method (therefore, version 2).
- With MediaType Version 1, the only match would be the wild card => getObjectV1.
- With MediaType Version 2, there is two matches (v1 and v2) but v2 is more specific => getObjectV2

  ```
  @GET
  @Path("/")
  public Object getObjectV1(){
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/")
  @Produces(value ={CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_CUSTOM_MEDIATYPE_JSON_V2})
  public Object getObjectV2(){
  }
  ```

http://bill.burkecentral.com/2013/05/29/the-poor-jax-rs-request-dispatching-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `*/*`:

```
@Produces(value = {MediaType.WILDCARD,
                   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                   CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_CUSTOM_MEDIATYPE_JSON_V2})
```

Comment: Hi Lutz, This is still returning the first version. As the client accepts all mimetypes JAXRS is matching both as possible candidate methods to be chosen but then it seems to always choose the first one. I want it by default to choose the one I dictate. Any ideas?